# How can sum group values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sum when the group state= 0,1,2 and sum 0 when it show 0

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 2                   1             0
   3      BILL                  3                   2             1
   4      LARRY                 4                   2             1
   5      MESSI                 1                   1             1  
   6      DROGBA                1                   1             1   

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         2 
     2     ROB          1
     3     SECURE       2
     4     ACCIDENT     1

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      BANK
    2      HOSPITAL

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      SPRINT
    2      APPLE
```

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/935e78/4
```

I'm trying to sum states = 0,1,2 in each column:

```
  SELECT 
   IF( p.state =0, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_0, 
   IF( p.state =1, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_1,
   IF( p.state =2, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_2, 
   p.policy_business_unit_id AS UNITS, 
   p.cia_ensure_id AS CIAS

FROM policies p
WHERE  p.policy_business_unit_id IN ( 1 ) 
AND p.cia_ensure_id =1
GROUP BY p.state
```

This is the result:

```
  STATE_0   STATE_1       STATE_2     UNITS    CIAS
    1           0          0           1       1
    0           2          0           1       1
```

How can I do to have this result?

```
  STATE_0   STATE_1       STATE_2     UNITS    CIAS
    1           2          0           1       1
```

Please I will appreciate all kind of help.
Thanks.

Comment: The query you wrote groups by `state` and there are 2 states in your records so there are 2 records. Try [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/935e78/12), this will give you what you need.

Comment: Just remove `GROUP BY p.state` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to group all values for state = 0 or 1 or 2 together, then your query must be a little different. Try this.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS state_0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS state_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.state = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS state_2,
    p.policy_business_unit_id AS UNITS, 
    p.cia_ensure_id AS CIAS 
FROM policies p
WHERE  p.policy_business_unit_id IN ( 1 ) 
    AND p.cia_ensure_id =1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN p.state IN (0,1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Here is a working [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/935e78/27) that shows how this works.

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
  SELECT 
   IF( p.state =0, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_0, 
   IF( p.state =1, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_1,
   IF( p.state =2, COUNT( p.state ) , 0 ) AS state_2,
```

by

```
 SELECT 
   sum(CASE WHEN p.state =0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 end) AS state_0, 
   sum(CASE WHEN p.state =1 THEN  1  ELSE 0  END) AS state_1,
   sum(CASE WHEN p.state =2 THEN  1  ELSE 0  END) AS state_2,
```

Comment: Tried your code but I have 2 rows and should be only one

Answer (score 0):

You might look at grouping by the policy_business_unit_id and cia_ensure_id in part because you may want to report not just for the 1 and 1 but all combinations.

```
SELECT 
sum(case when p.state = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS state_0, 
sum(case when p.state = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS state_1,
sum(case when p.state = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS state_2, 
p.policy_business_unit_id AS UNITS, 
p.cia_ensure_id AS CIAS
FROM policies p
--WHERE  p.policy_business_unit_id IN ( 1 ) 
--AND p.cia_ensure_id =1
group by p.policy_business_unit_id, p.cia_ensure_id
```